# Can't create a C# connection with mySQL

Tags: c#, mysql

Ok, so i'm trying to create a simple program with C#/.NET that requires a database. I've read some stuff and I tried to make that connection, but for some reason my computer can't connect to the server(localhost). I've successfully installed MySQL Connector/NET and MySQL on my PC, i'm using workbench to create the database tables. My code is:

```
 class DBconnect
{
    private MySqlConnection connection;
    private string server;
    private string database;
    private string uid;
    private string password;

    //Constructor
    public DBconnect()
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    //Initialize values
    private void Initialize()
    {
        server = "localhost";
        database = "clientsdb";
        uid = "root";
        password = "password";
        string connectionString;
        connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" + database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";
        //connectionString = "datasource=" + server + ";port=3306;username=" + uid + ";password=" + password + ";";

        connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
    }

    //open connection to database
    private bool OpenConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            return true;
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            //0: Cannot connect to server.
            //1045: Invalid user name and/or password.
            switch (ex.Number)
            {
                case 0:
                    MessageBox.Show("Cannot connect to server.  Contact administrator");
                    break;

                case 1045:
                    MessageBox.Show("Invalid username/password, please try again");
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I've tried both "connectionString"-s but when I try to use the OpenConnection function it gives me the cannot connect to server error.What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe this is not related to your code, but parameters . Your code seems legit you need to check if all parameters are okay .

Comment: Yes you were right, it was a parameter issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Using https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/ I get a connection string like this:

```
connectionString = "Server=" + server + ";" + "Database=" + database + ";" + "Uid=" + uid + ";" + "Pwd=" + password + ";";
```

which should work.